# Why does SyncAdapter create a default periodic sync even though I have not called addPeriodicSync()?

Tags: java, android, android-syncadapter

I have followed the [BasicSyncAdapter](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicSyncAdapter) example in the google samples and I wonder why a default periodic sync (sync interval 86400 secs or 24h) is even created if I [comment out the call to `addPeriodicSync()` function in the code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicSyncAdapter/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/basicsyncadapter/SyncUtils.java#L63).

I find no documentation whatsoever that creating a SyncAdapter and the stub code (SyncService, Authenticator account etc.) also creates a periodic sync with that default sync interval.

My Question: Is it possible to create a SyncAdapter without such default periodic sync?

Thanks.

BTW, this is how I detect the presence of periodic syncs.

```
java.util.List<PeriodicSync> periodicSyncsList = ContentResolver.getPeriodicSyncs(myaccount, CONTENT_AUTHORITY);
Log.d(TAG, "Number of syncs in the periodicSyncsList = " + periodicSyncsList.size());
for (PeriodicSync p : periodicSyncsList) {
    Log.d(TAG, p.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is little bit late, but I hope this answer could help to someone.

I found in this article http://blog.udinic.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter in section Automatic sync that setSyncAutomatically method will implicitly set periodic update to 24h.

So, resolution of your problem is just to change last argument in the following method call to false.

```
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, CONTENT_AUTHORITY, false);
```

I had similar issue with method call order. This will result to periodic sync interval set to value of SYNC_FREQUENCY.

```
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, CONTENT_AUTHORITY, true);
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, CONTENT_AUTHORITY, new Bundle(),SYNC_FREQUENCY);
```

But this method call order will result to 24h periodic sync interval.

```
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, CONTENT_AUTHORITY, new Bundle(),SYNC_FREQUENCY);
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, CONTENT_AUTHORITY, true);
```

Be aware of it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Setting a periodic sync appears to be a persistent operation. It means once set it stays active until you call `ContentProvider.removePeriodicSync` or you uninstall the app.

This means just commenting the `ContentProvider.addPeriodicSync` out does not help to get rid of it. Try to uninstall the app and run it again without calling `ContentProvider.addPeriodicSync`. Periodic sync must be disabled then.

Comment: Agreed, but what statement or operation creates this periodic sync? Wierdly or not, why is there no mention of this in the documentation :(

Comment: It's enough to call `ContentProvider.addPeriodicSync` just once and it will be registered. I agree that documentation is very thin and can be improved.

Comment: I think you may not have got what I meant in the question. My point is "How come a periodic sync exist without even calling addPeriodicSync() ?" When we comment that line of code (as I point out in the question), there is no way we are calling `Content.addPeriodicSync`.